# JavaFX Window Freezes During Execution?

Tags: java, javafx

For some reason, this snippet of code won't run correctly. When I run it, a blank window appears, freezes after 4 seconds or so, in which I have to terminate the execution. It's almost as if it fails to load fully; any reason why this might be happening?

[image: Blank window that appears shortly after execution]

Below is the relevant code from my project:

Main class:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    public static GUILauncher gl;
    public CommandGUIController cgc;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        startProgram(primaryStage);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void startProgram(Stage primaryStage){

        gl = new GUILauncher(primaryStage);

        cgc = new CommandGUIController();
        gl.showGUI("../view/CommandGUI.fxml", "../view/application.css", "JavaChat Client", cgc);

        println("Welcome to JavaChat");
        println("Server or Client mode? (Type \"1\" for Server, \"2\" for Client)");
        boolean isGoodInput = false;
        while(!isGoodInput){
            String in = sc.nextLine();
            if(in.equals("1")){
                isGoodInput = true;
                gl.showServerGUI();
            }
            if(in.equals("2")){
                isGoodInput = true;
                gl.showClientGUI();
            }
            if(!(in.equals("1")||(in.equals("2")))){
                System.out.println("Please try again... must be a number between 1 and 2 inclusively.");
            }
        }


    }

    public void println(String str){
        cgc.writeToOutput(str);
    }
}
```

GUILauncher class:

```
public class GUILauncher {

    private Stage primaryStage;

    public GUILauncher(Stage inS){
         primaryStage = inS;
    }    

    public void showGUI(String FXMLpath, String csspath, String title, Object controller){

        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(FXMLpath));               
            loader.setController(controller);
            Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);

            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource(csspath).toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.setTitle(title);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

Finally, CommandGUIController:

```
public class CommandGUIController implements Initializable, InputController {

    private String input;

    @FXML
    private TextArea outputArea;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @FXML
    public void enterInput(KeyEvent e){
        if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER){
            input = outputArea.getText().substring(outputArea.getText().lastIndexOf("\n") + 1);
            //System.out.println(input);
        }
    }

    public void writeToOutput(String str){
        outputArea.appendText(str + "\n");
    }

    public String getInput(){
        return input;
    }

    public void setInput(String strInput){
        input = strInput;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: CommandGUI.fxml as requested:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <GridPane layoutX="114.0" layoutY="110.0" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <columnConstraints>
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="40.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="40.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
          <RowConstraints maxHeight="50.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints maxHeight="50.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <TextArea fx:id="outputArea" onKeyPressed="#enterInput" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" wrapText="true" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
         </children>
      </GridPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

EDIT2 (IMPORTANT): After some more testing, I think I realize that the code I initially left out of main has to do with the freezing. The program hung at sc.nextLine(), and was awaiting input.

Regardless; I still have this issue; the GUI shows up completely blank, even after I show it in gl.showGUI() of the main. I decided to try a few more tests, and eliminate the loop from the code, and the GUI finally loads at the end; it almost seems like it has to resolve before it can be seen? Yet, this doesn't make sense, the GUI should load before the println() code runs so that I can interact with it. Why does the GUI show up at the very end? How can I fix this, do I have to run a separate thread, or is there a method I can call that will force it to load before moving on to the next line? Thanks again for reading

Comment: Does anything appear in your console? Any error?

Comment: Nothing. It just kind of freezes, and so inevitably I have to terminate it.

Comment: Provide the code of CommandGUI.fxml view. I assume the cause of failure there.

Comment: I just made an important update after some testing, I think I'm getting closer to the core of the issue. The GUI doesn't completely load for some reason, it just shows that blank screen you see right after the gl.showGUI(). I have to remove the loop and "clear the way" for the code to end for the FXML and CSS to kick in; am I missing anything? Thanks!

Comment: i think you need to take away the while loop bro

Comment: The thing is, it hangs at sc.nextLine(), so even if I take away the while loop, the issue will still remain